Need speech recognition library for android app
I'm looking for a speech recognition library which has got accuracy > 95% and average response time < 400ms. This is needed for one of my native ANDROID app which has been running on propriety android tablets that don't have Google play services and hence I cannot use native Google speech APIs in first place.
If you have used or tried any speech recognition library that can work without Google speech recognition APIs, please feel free to share about it or references link or anything that you can think can be helpful in this regard. Thanks in advance.
I already tried few libraries like Viosk but didn't meet my accuracy and latency requirements.

The Android SDK has a built-in SpeechRecognizer class. This class provides real-time Speech Recognition in Android.
Please note that the application must have Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO permission to use this class.
Here is the official documentation.
Edit: You can have a look at this project for reference.

Thanks Samudra for inputs but as I mentioned in my post, I cannot use SpeechRecognizer as it works only on devices with play services.
